# Xamarin Android KitKat Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I've just installed Xamarin in VS2017 (15.3).

Following https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/introduction_to_kitkat/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/

The project file has Application android compile version set to *Android 4.4 (Kit Kat)*.
Android manifest min and target version are both set to `Android 4.4 (API Level 19 - Kit Kat)`

For the debugger I have selected the

```
5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone (Android 4.4 - API 19).
```

(7" tablet did also not work).

When I build/rebuild I get:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Phoneword, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>  Phoneword -> E:\Source\Workspaces\Phoneword\Phoneword\bin\Debug\Phoneword.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I try to debug I get: "There were deployment errors. Continue?"

1>------ Build started: Project: Phoneword, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

```
1>  Phoneword -> E:\Source\Workspaces\Phoneword\Phoneword\bin\Debug\Phoneword.dll
2>Starting deploy 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
2>Starting emulator 5" KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone ...
2>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
2>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Error list:

```
IDE0006 Error encountered while loading the project. Some project features, such as full solution analysis for the failed project and projects that depend on it, have been disabled.
```

In the log (Help > Xamarin > Open Logs) I see:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.get_JoinableTaskContext()
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Emulator.Utilities.VsTelemetryHelper.LogEvent(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String eventPath, IDictionary`2 properties)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Emulator.Logging.VsEmulatorTelemetryLogger.LogEvent(String eventName, IDictionary`2 properties)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Emulator.Logging.DeviceTelemetryLogger.LogEvent(String eventName, IDictionary`2 properties)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Emulator.EmulatorService.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<StartAsync>b__0()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.Devices.MicrosoftAndroidDeviceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<<StartEmulator>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\d\lanes\4985\306f76ac\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\MicrosoftAndroidDeviceProvider.cs:line 114
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTaskFactory.Run[T](Func`1 asyncMethod, JoinableTaskCreationOptions creationOptions)
 at Merq.AsyncManager.Run[T](Func`1 asyncMethod) in C:\projects\merq\src\Async\Merq.Async.Core\Merq.Async.Core.Portable\AsyncManager.cs:line 64
 at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.Devices.MicrosoftAndroidDeviceProvider.StartEmulator(IAndroidVirtualDevice virtualDevice, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\d\lanes\4985\306f76ac\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Devices\MicrosoftAndroidDeviceProvider.cs:line 114
 at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.StartUp(IMonoAndroidDevice device, IProgressReport progress, IAndroidVirtualDeviceProvider virtualDeviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\d\lanes\4985\306f76ac\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 75
 at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.Execute(StartupVirtualDeviceCommand command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\d\lanes\4985\306f76ac\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\StartupVirtualDeviceCommandHandler.cs:line 48
 at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\d\lanes\4985\306f76ac\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 151
 at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`2.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() in C:\d\lanes\4985\306f76ac\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 117
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---


 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.DeployCommandHandler.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<<StartUpVirtualDeviceAndDeploy>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\d\lanes\4985\306f76ac\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\DeployCommandHandler.cs:line 240
```

when opening Main.axml I get:

```
mono.android.DesignerException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at mono.android.DesignerException.fromThrowable(DesignerException.java:46)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.checkRenderResultForError(DesignerSession.java:187)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:239)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.processMessage(DesignerSession.java:704)
at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The main Looper has already been prepared.
at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:104)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.prepareThread(Bridge.java:544)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:426)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:368)
at mono.android.DesignerSession.load(DesignerSession.java:233)
... 4 more
```

Any suggestions? 
The Android SDK Manager I have installed Android SDK Build-tools 19.1 and Android 4.4.2 (API 19).

(19.1 because 19.0.3 / 19.0.2 / 19.0.1 / 19 are obsolete).

any suggestions on how to get this working?

(needed to write an app on samsung SM-T560 with android 4.4.4)

Comment: I'm getting the same with an app that works and builds on another machine with vs2017 on it, but not the latest versions of everything (was upgraded from rc1)  This laptop I wiped and installed 2017.3 from scratch, and have this problem.  Android emulator (non -vs one) works ok once I turn hyper V off, but it's too slow for general debugging.

Comment: can't deploy to emulator.
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2047-08-11) or after any future revocation date.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "E:\Source\Workspaces\Phoneword\Phoneword\bin\Debug\Phoneword.Phoneword-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\Phoneword.Phoneword-Signed.apk" 
Done building project "Phoneword.csproj" -- FAILED.

Answer (score 0):

Think I fixed it - launch the "Visual Studio emulator for Android" manually from the start menu/app list, then launch the one you're after manually from within the VS emulator tool, this fires it up and initialises it.  Next time I tried from within VS it worked ok.  You can use the emulator UI to download other profiles and API levels as well, these will then show in the VS2017 Start/Debug dropdown as options.

Comment: If I set the "Compile using Android version:" to Android 5.0 (lollipop) instead of 6.0 (Marshmellow). I can run my app.
can't get it working on kitkat and can't get it working on marshmellow... -_-